# Can't checkout another repo in my Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I run the pipeline, either by pushing a commit to the repo or doing it manually, I get this error:

> Checkout of repository 'repo1' is not supported. Only 'self', 'none',
> or a repository alias are supported.

I'm using Azure DevOps Services with the free tier on my own account where I'm the admin.

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
  resources:
    repositories:
    - repository: repo1
      type: git
      name: testing/repo1
      ref: main
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
           - main

stages:
- stage: 'Build'

  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: repo1

      - script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

Comment: Please ensure your YAML is correctly formatted, as YAML is whitespace-sensitive. Nothing looks wrong here except for the formatting, so you probably have a whitespace issue. `resources` is indented under `pool`. If your YAML actually looks like that, that's definitely incorrect.

Comment: Wow. That solved it. Thank you! I can't believe Azure doesn't give you a better warning to help you solve this, but oh well.

Comment: @Rattletrap Glad to know that the issue has been resolved. You can add an answer to share the steps to resolve the issue and accept it. This will be helpful to other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to fix the indentation of resources. It should be at the same level as "pool" and "trigger".